# How to center text and prevent text from overflowing using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My UI currently looks like this:

[image: My UI]

I want to center the text in the middle of the space that is left over after the image is placed. However, I also want to make sure that my text does not overflow due to the size. How can I do that? My code is as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 0,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Text(
                        name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Text(
                        modalityText,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this is one way of doing what you want

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 0,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage("imageUrl"),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Text(
                          "name",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: Text(
                          "modalityText",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```